# UK - Getting a Certificate of Sponsorship

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas

I lived in the UK for one year as an exchange student. During this period I did a Summer internship and it was a brilliant experience. For this reason I would like work in the UK after I graduate. I have done some research about it and this is what I've found out: (please correct me if I'm wrong)

- I would need to apply for a Tier 2 (General) Visa since I'm from outside the European Economic Area (EEA).
- I would need a Certificate of Sponsorship (CoS) from an employer in order to get the visa.
- In consideration of my degree, the job title would be among the ones listed in the Shortage Occupation List. Therefore, the employer wouldn't have to carry out a resident labour market.

My question is: how hard is it to get a Certificate of Sponsorship? I know it varies on a case-by-case basis, but any information would be helpful. Additionally, does company size affects my chances of getting a CoS? Are bigger companies more likely to provide me a CoS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard now and it will get harder given that a majority in Commons favours the immigration manifesto.

Comment: If you can please split it up - we try to keep one post per question.  You've asked two, arguably three in there :/